# How to use `parse` to get all lines with all search strings in Red language

Tags: parsing, rebol, red

I am trying to extract from a list of lines which have all of the strings from a list of search strings. I am trying following code using `and` keyword (as mentioned on http://rebol.com/r3/docs/concepts/parsing-summary.html ) to include only those lines that have all strings of srchstr block:

```
lines: [ 
    "this is first (1st) line"
    "second line"
    "third line"
    "this is second sentence"
    "first line or sentence"
    "third sentence"    ]

srchstr: ["line" "first"]

probe parse lines [and reduce srchstr]
probe parse lines [and srchstr]
```

There is no error message but the output is only:

```
false
false
```

I also tried:

```
foreach line lines 
    [parse line [and srchstr]
        (print line)]
```

But this prints all lines.

Desired output is:

```
    [ 
    "this is first (1st) line"
    "first line or sentence"
    ]
```

It will be obvious from these codes that I am very new to this, though I have tried to read about it.

Where is the problem and how can I get the desired output?

Comment: Are you only looking for whole words or any substring?

Comment: Only whole words (to keep it simple for the moment!).

Comment: `probe` is more useful in the middle. Also `parse-trace`

Comment: The `and` command in Red's Parse is called `ahead`.

Comment: Is it `ahead` or "`ahead to`" (as used everywhere on this page) ? Also `ahead` is not mentioned on http://rebol.com/r3/docs/concepts/parsing-summary.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match whole words, both versions will use a `parse` pre-pass to extract said words:

```
extract-words: func [series [string!]][
    letters: charset [#"0" - #"9" #"a" - #"z"]
    series: parse series [collect any [keep some letters | skip]]
]
```

### Using FIND

This creates a block of `find` results and confirms compliance with `all`:

```
contains-all: func [series [string!] words [block!] /local word][
    series: extract-words series

    all collect [
        foreach word words [
            keep find series word 
        ]
        keep true
    ]
]
```

Then you can loop through your strings to find matches:

```
collect [
    foreach line [ 
        "this is first (1st) line"
        "second line"
        "third line"
        "this is second sentence"
        "first line or sentence"
        "third sentence"
    ][
        if contains-all line ["line" "first"][keep line]
    ]
]
```

### Using PARSE

This version creates a `parse` rule that will match against `sort`ed words:

```
contains-all: function [series [string!] words [block!]][
    parse sort extract-words series collect [
        foreach word sort copy words [
            keep 'thru
            keep word
        ]
        keep [to end]
    ]
]
```

Comment: I find that I can remove `to logic!` without any loss of correct output. Is it really needed?

Comment: Also, this simple code gives error: `foreach line lines if contains-all line srchstr [probe line]` . The error is : *** Script Error: line has no value; *** Where: contains-all; *** Stack: contains-all . Why is this not working?

Comment: @rnso Updated to reflect the 'whole words' stipulation. Should work now. `to logic!` gives you a `true` or `false` result. Without it, you get either a string (successful `find`) or none (unsuccessful).

Comment: I think `all` returns true if none of them is `none`, else it returns false, hence it works without `to logic!` also.

Comment: @rnso Not so—try `all [find "foo" "f"]`. It will still work, but the return value may be misleading.

Comment: I think you should also keep 'contains-all' version without extract-series that you had posted earlier. It was easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

This is no typical task for parse, but better solved with foreach .. ..[all [..]]

```
>> foreach line lines [all [find line srchstr/1 find line srchstr/2 print line]]
this is first (1st) line
first line or sentence
```

a variant with the condition composed dynamically from multiple search strings

```
foreach line lines compose/only  [ 
    all   (
        collect [ 
            foreach str srchstr [
                keep compose [find line (str)] 
            ] 
            keep [print line]
        ]  
    ) 
]
```

Ok, a crude parse solution with multiple strings in the search block

```
>> rule:  [collect some into [   keep to end | to end ] ]
== [collect some into [keep to end | to end]]
>> foreach str srchstr [ insert  rule/4  compose [ahead to (str)] ] 
== [ahead to "line" keep to end | to end]
>> parse lines rule
== ["this is first (1st) line" "first line or sentence"]
```

Comment: There may be more than 2 strings in srchstr block so it has to be able to take variable number of entries in srchstr.

Comment: Hm, could do as an extra long one-liner: `parse lines compose/deep [collect some into [(collect [foreach str srchstr [keep [ahead to] keep str]]) keep to end | to end]]`. Could probably use some explanation though...

Comment: It will be useful if you could mention parse code if just one string is to be tested for multiple search strings present in a series (srchstr here).